# how to resolve $rootScope:infdig

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

A sample application is at: http://jsfiddle.net/qvkyrg7k/8/, why do I get $rootScope:infdig?

Basically I'm trying to take an array of items, filter by a search term and then group based on a property so I can show in a tree like way.

The problematic line is

```
 <tr ng-repeat-start="(family, members) in data | filter:search | groupByFamily">
```

Comment: You know you could use two filters, first filter the list then use a custom filter to group it.  It will be even faster this way since you have less to group

Comment: It will not be faster since the first filter will create a new list which the custom filter will then use to create the result object. But it is cleaner.

Comment: @IttayD can you modify [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvkyrg7k/) for reproducing your problem?

Comment: sure: http://jsfiddle.net/qvkyrg7k/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10738 for the reason and track. Basically, ngRepeat watches the result of the pipe using $watchCollection. Since groupByFamily creates new arrays each time it is run, angular thinks the whole model changed and triggers a rerender which then makes groupByFamily run again, etc.

Comment: but if element in array is primitive, like `[1,2,3]` - all works